# Minified variable for javascript forloop is wrongly minified?

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer-8, minify, uglifyjs

I am using UglifyJS to minify js. I've noticed that:

```
var start = 0;
for( var t = start; t<k.length; t++)
```

The t is replaced with

```
var t=!0
```

What is going on here? I know !0 === true, but this is throwing errors for IE8. It doesn't throw any error for other modern browsers but I am not sure they are actually working as expected.

Edit: example here

```
var start = 0;

function scan() {
  var hello = true;
  for (var j = start; j < 3; j++) {
  }

  return hello;
}
```

After minify using Uglify

```
function scan(){for(var a=!0,b=start;3>b;b++);return a}var start=0;
```

Comment: That comma should be a semicolon

Comment: ... and what exotic construct is a var-for loop?

Comment: Ok guys, instead of pointing out the typos there(I do appreciate it), any idea if this is an error?

Comment: Well, for me it returns `for(var start=0,t=start;t<k.length;t++);`

Comment: Can you show us more of the code you are trying to minify?  When I test this in UglifyJS, I don't get the same issue you do.

Comment: So, what's the ***actual*** issue here?  What *errors* does IE 8 give?

Comment: In a `for` statement, you can define as many vars as you want in the 1st "section", not just one.  So, it just does `var a=!0,b=start;` *in* the `for` because it's shorter.  It's still the same functionality.  P.S. You `for` loop has no body; I assume in you real code that you have stuff in there?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat, I missed the part where it creates two variables inside for(). It appears earlier in ie8 debugger, but I can't reproduced it anymore.  I'll have to dig into the code in body. Thank you for explanation.